# Algorithms complexity

Tags: algorithm

i need some help with algorithms complexity, i should be able to answer questions like these:

1. Let f(n) and g(n) denote the message complexity of the Chang & Roberts algorithm in the best and in the average case, respectively.
   Which of the following asymptotic relations is wrong?

   a) f(n) = Θ(g(n))
   b) f(n) = O(g(n))
   c) f(n) = o(g(n))
   d) g(n) = Ω(g(n))
2. Let f(n) and g(n) denote the message complexity of the Chang & Roberts algorithm in the worst and in the average case, respectively. Which of the following asymptotic relations is wrong?

   a) f(n) = Θ(g(n))
   b) f(n) = Ω(g(n))
   c) f(n) = !(g(n))
   d) f(n) = O(g(n))

I know that complexities for Chang & Roberts algorithm are:

Θ(n^2)      worst case

Θ(n)        best case

Θ(n log n)  average case

The answer to question 1 is a, for question 2 are a,d.
I know the differences (definitions) between Θ, O e Ω but i'm not able to apply them to these questions. Can you help me?

For example, in the 1st question, is it correct to see answers in this way?

```
f(n) = Θ(n), g(n) = Θ(n log n)

a) Θ(n) = Θ(Θ(n log n)) 
b) Θ(n) = O(Θ(n log n)) 
c) Θ(n) = o(Θ(n log n)) 
d) g(n) = Ω(Θ(n log n))
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not homework solving service.

Comment: @xenteros obviously you didn't read all the post, since i put also the answers to the questions

Comment: Those nested O's and thetas and omegas are relatively nonsensical. The proper way to express those things is eg Θ(n) ⊆ Θ(n log n). They're sets.

Comment: @harold are you suggesting to remove Θ, O or Ω that are inside brackets? For example, o(Θ(n^2)) must be readed as o(n^2) ?

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: To those who voted to close: "not a homework service" is a subset of "Too broad"; please don't use "other" for this.

Comment: `f(n) = Θ(n)` is never true, because left side of the equality is a function and the right side of the equality is a set. `a-d` are illegal expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first question, f(n)=Θ(g(n)) iff f(n) and g(n) are asymptotically equal.
But n and nlogn are not asymptotically equal. So a is the answer.

For more explanation, see the 2nd option. f(n)=O(g(n)) iff g(n) is asymptotically greater than or equal to f(n). So, n=O(nlogn) is correct.

See the 3rd option. f(n)=o(g(n)) iff g(n) is asymptotically greater than f(n). So, n=o(nlogn) is correct as nlogn is asymptotically greater than n.

See the 4th option. f(n)=Ω(g(n)) iff g(n) is asymptotically lesser or equal to f(n). So, nlogn=Ω(nlogn) is correct as they are asymptotically equal.

I solved only the first one to show the approach. Try with the second one.

Comment: are you suggesting to remove Θ, O or Ω that are inside brackets? For example, o(Θ(n^2)) must be readed as o(n^2) ?

Comment: Yes, n^2 and Θ(n^2) are same. By the way,where did I mention to remove Θ, O or Ω? If you are clear with comparing functions asymptotically, then my explanation should be clear to you.

Comment: Option b is O(Θ(n log n)) and you said n=O(nlogn), so you removed Θ, or not? Probabily i'm confused with comparing functions

Comment: Yes, you can do that because f(n) and Θ(f(n)) are asymptotically equal.

Comment: and the same is for O and Ω? For example o(O(n^2)) is equal to o(n^2) ? Why in the 3rd option you use O and not o ?

Comment: No only for Θ it this is applicable. And sorry for that, I edited it.

Comment: So, in case of f(n) = O(Θ(n)) it's always equivalent to f(n) = O(n) ? Θ can be always omitted? And what happen if we have f(n) = Ω(O(n)) ? How is readed the right side?

Answer (score 0):

> For example, in the 1st question, is it correct to see answers in this way?

```
f(n) = Θ(n), g(n) = Θ(n log n)
```

No, because left sides are functions and right sides are sets.

```
a) Θ(n) = Θ(Θ(n log n)) 
b) Θ(n) = O(Θ(n log n)) 
c) Θ(n) = o(Θ(n log n)) 
d) g(n) = Ω(Θ(n log n))
```

a-d: No, because set is not equal to set applied to another set. You can't use set as a function.

You might be looking for set operations like sum and intersect.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem and i'm still confused with this. Can you suggest me something to read about set operations?

Comment: Yea, introduction to algorithms by Cormen